# ROS Beginner Tutorials: Examining the Simple Service and Client (python) - need some help with Client 2

Tags: ros, python, service, beginner-tutorials, rosservices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I'm following the **ROS Tutorials** and, using the *Python* language, I'm currently having some issues trying to solve the item **Examining the Simple Service and Client** item (http ://www.ros .org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/ExaminingServiceClient). I was already having a problem with the server in this tutorial, but it was solved in another thread (in [link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/70546/ros-beginner-tutorials-examining-the-simple-service-and-client-python-need-some-help/))

My situation is the following:

- I run `roscore` in a terminal
- I run the server (`rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_server.py`) in another, getting `Ready to add two ints.`
- But when I try to run the client (`rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_client.py 1 3`), I get the following:

  [rospack] Error: stack/package beginner_tutorials not found

Running `roswtf` gives me the following:

```
viki@ROS:~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts$ roswtf
Package: beginner_tutorials
Cannot find dependencies for package [beginner_tutorials]: missing beginner_tutorials
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/groovy/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
viki@ROS:~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts$
```

Can anybody help me? I haven't found any clues on the web related to this and I can't figure it out what's really happening.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance,

Batta

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71260/ros-beginner-tutorials:-examining-the-simple-service-and-client-(python)---need-some-help-with-client-2/) by [Batta](https://answers.ros.org/users/5117/batta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-08-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-08-05**:
what is the output of `export | grep ROS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree with Gustavo's suggestion.  It seems to me that your `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is probably not set correctly in the terminal you're using to run the client.

It looks like you're using catkin.  Remember that you need to source the catkin workspace `setup.bash` file in **each** new terminal (`source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`).  This will update the `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` for that terminal.  You can check this using the command Gustavo referenced above: `export | grep ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.  Also, `rospack find beginner_tutorials` should find the correct path to your package.

I can't see where this requirement is covered explicitly in the ROS tutorials.  You can see some hints when reading through [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying#Testing_Out_Your_Overlaid_Packages) section, but it could definitely be made more clear.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5